# Read raw HD partition in Linux at a particular offset

Tags: linux, grep, ext3

I'm trying to recover some files deleted from a Linux ext3 partition. I've grepped the raw partition device (/dev/sda1) using `grep -b` and it gave me an offset. What's the easiest way for me to read a chunk of data from that block device starting from the offset returned by grep?

Comment: Also have a look at [debugfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs). Online tutorials exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dd`: set the block size to `1k` to simplify the math, then `skip` that number of blocks to (just before) the offset and copy however many `count` of blocks you think you might need, using the partition as the input file, to an output file:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=recovery_file bs=1k skip=4321 count=20
```